DescriptorSetFileName and protoSourceRoot params" and how to point it to my protofile jar?
I like to use the karate-grpc but I'm confussed about the demo config and how to setup for my project. I have an jar dependency in my project lib folder for the proto files, added the karate-grpc dependency in my Gradle file. And then where should the "descriptorSetFileName and protoSourceRoot params" and how to point it to my protofile jar?
Thanks for the help
Marc
I tried to follow the https://github.com/pecker-io/karate-grpc demo project but I have no idea where to start.

unfortunately that project you are referring to is not maintained anymore. you can see if this example helps: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/grpc/README.md
